# Creating a reponsive input form with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

[image]

---

I am trying to realize the screen shown on the screenshot. But I cannot control the space between elements. I want it to be responsive but I guess I cannot manage the high res screen layout this time. The code is below and I have added a wireframe of the screen.
When adding some elements with prepend it always ruins my deams :)

link to file: [jsfiddle.net/AmhHf](http://jsfiddle.net/AmhHf)

```
![<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8">
      <h1>Formulate</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="span4 pull-right">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <form class="well span12">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
          <label>Formula Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="span8"> 
        </div>
        <div class="span8">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
          <label>My Label</label>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
          <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on">@</span>
            <input type="text" class="input-medium"> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">+</div>
        <div class="span3">
          <select>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
          <label>My Label</label>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
          <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on">@</span>
            <input type="text" class="input-medium"> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">+</div>
        <div class="span3">
          <select>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
          <label>My Label</label>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
          <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on">@</span>
            <input type="text" class="input-medium"> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">+</div>
        <div class="span3">
          <select>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid"></div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
          <label>My Label</label>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
          <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on">@</span>
            <input type="text" class="input-medium"> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">+</div>
        <div class="span3">
          <select>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="form-actions pull-right">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          <input type="reset" class="btn" value="Reset"> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>][3]
```

Edit:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Pagetitle</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- HTML5 shim for IE backwards compatibility -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: Link to an example would be really helpful.

Comment: An example? Actually there is none :( but http://jsfiddle.net/AmhHf/ tried it on jsfiddle, maybe this can help.

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the bootstrap-responsive file. You might have the @media queries in your main bootstrap too but I couldn't see them there.

Comment: Stefan, sorry I do not have any media queries.

Comment: In this case check out the info on this page:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: I think you did not get what the problem is. The structure of the code has a problem, <div class="span3">+</div> are not shown, it is not responding how it should :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be related to [a bug in bootstrap](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6414) that will be resolved in v3.

As per one of the comments in that link, for now you can use this jQuery snippet to resolve the issue:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $(".input-prepend, .input-append").each(function(index, group) {
      var input = $("input", group).css('width', '');
      $(".add-on, .btn", group).each(function() {
        input.css('width', '-=' + $(this).outerWidth());
      });
    });
  }).trigger('resize');
});
```

And I'd recommend changing the class of your inputs to `input-block-level`.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span3">
    <label>My Label</label>
  </div>
  <div class="span3">
    <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">@</span>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level"/> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span3">+</div>
  <div class="span3">
    <select class="input-block-level">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

See this [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmather/kUaZV/1/) and how the first line of inputs now resizes correctly.